# Splitting string on a delimiter

Tags: r, string, split

I have a data frame with rows that look like this:

```
Rank..Player      Pos Team PosRank
1. Le'Veon Bell    RB  PIT     RB1
2. Todd Gurley II  RB  LAR     RB2
```

The issue is that the numbers and names in the first column are one string, and some names have periods in them, making it somewhat trickier to split the two:

```
18. A.J. Green  WR  CIN  WR7
```

All solutions I've seen involve splitting strings that contain only numbers and letters. I need a way to split the first column in a way that won't split names like the one above.

Here is the code I used to scrape the data from ESPN:

```
df <- read_html("http://www.espn.com/fantasy/football/story/_/page/
      18RanksPreseason300nonPPR/2018-fantasy-football-non-ppr-rankings-top-300")

ranks <- df %>%
  html_nodes("table.inline-table") %>%
  .[[2]] %>%
  html_table()
```

Comment: Which from the above is your actual current data or data frame, and what is your expected output?

Comment: I simply want the number and names to be in 2 separate columns. Both examples are the current data.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub` to create a `delimiter` and then separate into two column with `read.csv`

```
tmp <- read.csv(text=sub("^(\\d+)\\.\\s+(.*)", "\\1,\\2", 
             ranks[[1]]), header = FALSE, col.names =c("Rank", "Player"))
ranks1 <- cbind(tmp, ranks[-1])
head(ranks1, 2)
#   Rank         Player Pos Team PosRank
#1    1   Le'Veon Bell  RB  PIT     RB1
#2    2 Todd Gurley II  RB  LAR     RB2
```

---

Or with `separate`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(ranks, `Rank, Player`, into = c("Rank", "Player"), sep="(?<=[0-9])\\.")
```

EDIT: Based on @AndS comments

Comment: I think with your separate solution, you will truncate any name with periods such as "18. A.J. Green" I suggest `separate(ranks, `Rank, Player`, into = c("Rank", "Player"), sep="(?<=\\d)\\.")`. That will work around that issue.

Comment: No problem. Just noticed it whilst scrolling

Comment: @akrun I wasn't insinuating that your code does not work at all.  I was trying to distinguish my answer as being intended for a situation where someone wants to add new columns to an already existing data frame.  Your answer is preferred here, because it fixes the data before it even gets read into R or stored +1.

Comment: I believe `sub("\\.",",",ranks[[1]])` is sufficient. since `sub` will only substitute the first `[.]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option using `strsplit`:

```
df <- data.frame(x <- "2. Todd Gurley II", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
out <- strsplit(df$x, "(?<=\\d)\\.\\s+", perl=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(df, do.call(rbind, out))
names(df) <- c("RankPlayer", "Rank", "Player")
df

         RankPlayer Rank         Player
1 2. Todd Gurley II    2 Todd Gurley II
```

### Demo